# Does saving a file release RAM memory?

Tags: memory

I do have a pretty big Photoshop file open with lots of unsaved changes. The Photoshop process is using lots of RAM (70%). I assume a temporary file with my changes is saved in the computer hard disk and not in RAM.

Doing a very basic test (firing up Windows Task Manager and saving my PS file), the process seems to release memory, bringing down the usage percentage to around 55%.

Is it right to assume that by saving changes to a file I'm releasing memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Previous to the save, the machine has to hold all edits in memory. On save, it can release that.